# Python - for loop exits 'prematurely'

Tags: python, for-loop, sqlite

EDIT: 
ANSWER: I needed to create another cursor for the 'einlesen()' function.

This is my first time using SQLite3 in Python, so excuse my (maybe) horrible syntax ;)
I'm trying to build kind of a DVD-Database, which fetches necessary information (actors etc.) directly from amazon. The whole program is based upon SQLite3 and Python 2.7.

Everything works well, except my plannes "update" feature.

```
def update():
    print 'Update Datenbank....bitte warten....'
    cursor.execute('''SELECT titel, amazon, erhalten, ausgeliehen FROM movies''')
    antwort = 'update'
    for row in cursor:
        stelle = row[1]
        ausg = row[2]
        erh = row[3]
        einlesen(stelle, ausg, erh, antwort)
        print row[0]
    raw_input('Update komplett!')
    menu()
```

The problem is, the loop exits after one iteration.

The output looks like this:

```
Update Datenbank....bitte warten....
#a few seconds pass
The Day After Tommorrow
Update komplett!
```

So I see, the loop and the function call are correct (the database gets updated correctly - done by the function 'einlesen()'), but there are more iterations, not just one...
So my question is: What is wrong? ;)

Here is the (abbreviated) 'einlesen()' function:

```
def einlesen(asin, ausg, erh, antwort):
    d = {}
    infos = urllib.urlopen('http://www.amazon.de/dp/'+asin).read()
    titel = infos[infos.find('Kaufen Sie')+11:infos.find('nstig ein')-3]
    art = 'dvd'
    infos = remove_html_tags(infos)
    infos = infos[infos.find('Darsteller: '):infos.find('Durchschnittliche')]
    infos = infos.split('\n')
    for x in range(200):
        try:
            infos.remove('')
        except:
            break
    for element in infos:
            d[element.split(': ')[0].lstrip()] = element.split(': ')[1]

#(excluded the whole Info-Scraping process)

    if antwort == 'update':
        movie = dauer, art, regie, jahr, fsk, darsteller, titel
        sql = ('''UPDATE movies SET laufzeit = ?, art = ?, regie = ?, jahr = ?, fsk =     ?, darsteller = ? WHERE titel = ?''')
        cursor.execute(sql, movie)
        connection.commit()
    else:
        menu()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your execute an `UPDATE` while you are still looping over the result of the `SELECT`. This drops the result of the first `cursor.execute()`.

Use a second cursor.

**Edit:**

```
cur1 = con.cursor()
cur2 = con.cursor()

cur1.execute("SELECT ...")
for row in cur1:
    cur2.execute("UPDATE ...")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!
How exactly do I creaty another cursor?